# Show a list of records to have a join to another table using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have an application that stores Posts and Topics and joins them using a Topic_Posts table.

The associations for the application are as follows:

```
Post.php
class Post extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Post';

    public $belongsTo = 'User';

    public $hasMany = array('Answer');

    // Has many topics that belong to topic post join table... jazz
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Topic' => array('with' => 'TopicPost')
    );
}

Topic.php
class Topic extends AppModel
{
    public $hasMany = array(
        'TopicPost'
    );
}

TopicPost.php
class TopicPost extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Topic', 'Post'
    );
}
```

When a user views a topic e.g. `/topics/view/topicname` I want to show all the posts that contain that Topic.

So far I have the following method in my TopicsController for the view:

```
public function view ( $slug )
{
    $topic = $this->Topic->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Topic.slug'=>$slug)));
    $this->set('topic', $topic);
    $this->set('title_for_layout', $topic['Topic']['title'] . ' &ndash; Topics');

    $this->paginate = array
    (
        'Post' => array
        (
            'limit'=>15,
            'conditions'=>array
            (
                'Post.status'=>array(1,2),
                'TopicPost.topic_id' => $topic['Topic']['id'],
            ),
            'order'=>array('Post.datetime'=>'desc'),
            'contain'=>array('User'=>'Profile', 'TopicPost')
        )
    );

    $posts = $this->paginate('Post'); // this one

    $this->set('posts', $posts);
```

}

And so that I can use Posts and TopicPosts I have added: `public $uses = array('Topic','TopicPost','Post');` to the top of the controller and made all models act as containable.

So basically I need to find Posts that have a match in the database model TopicPosts for the id of the topic I'm viewing.

Comment: Heh, it's nice that you added bounty reputation, but this is really bugging me. It should work! Can you post a pastie of your database structure with some sample data? And the updated code you have would also be useful.

Comment: This SQL would build the DB http://pastebin.com/qm72Rz6k and i've updated the code in the OP to be what I have now!

Comment: Also just to note the DB structure and relationships work fine as I can pull the topics for a post fine using TopicPost so I KNOW that works, it's just getting Posts for a topic that seems to be not working...

Comment: Another update of my answer..wish me luck :P

Comment: YES! :) error free. Thanks pal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just couldn't get it to work the "proper" way. I'm not sure if this is a bug in cake or something, but the paginate function simply refuses to budge.. The proper way to do this would probably be to write your own paginate function in your Post model, there is some info on how to do that in the cookbook.

Meanwhile, I offer you the workaround below. It's not optimal (at least not without caching) but it works. You can do it the proper way when/if you run into performance problem, but until then, this code below should do it.

```
public function view ( $slug )
{
    $topic = $this->Topic->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Topic.slug'=>$slug)));
    $this->set('topic', $topic);
    $this->set('title_for_layout', $topic['Topic']['title'] . ' &ndash; Topics');

    // step 1: get post IDs related to your topic
    $postIDs = $this->Topic->TopicPost->find
        (
            'list',
            array
            (
                'fields'        => array('TopicPost.post_id'),
                'conditions'    => array('TopicPost.topic_id' => $topic['Topic']['id'])
            )
        );

    $this->paginate = array
    (
        'Post' => array
        (
            'limit'=>15,
            'conditions'=>array
            (
                'Post.status' => array(1,2),
                // step 2: include them in your paginate conditions
                'Post.id' => $postIDs,
            ),
            'order' => array('Post.datetime'=>'desc'),
        )
    );

    $posts = $this->paginate('Post');

    $this->set('posts', $posts);
}
```

(Please note that I've stripped some of the stuff in my tests as I didn't have some of the stuff in your app, so don't forget to put it back)

Comment: Boom seems to have fixed it the error :) Any ideas on how to get the part of ONLY showing posts that are in the join table?

Comment: @Cameron: Hm, forgot about that..are you getting your posts in the first query? What is the output when you do a `debug($topic)` If you have your posts there, you could do a Set::extract() to get all post IDs and then add them to your pagination conditions.

Comment: Hmm that seems sloppy... Can't I just find the Posts that have a relationship to the topic in TopicPosts?

Comment: @Cameron: I've updated the post with possible answer to your question. Would something like this suffice?

Comment: Gives me this error: `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'TopicPost.topic_id' in 'where clause'` I've even added the TopicPost model to the uses var at the top of the controller so not sure what else to do?

Comment: Here is the SQL for that error: `SQL Query: SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`user_id`, `Post`.`datetime`, `Post`.`modified`, `Post`.`title`, `Post`.`slug`, `Post`.`content`, `Post`.`status`, `Post`.`latitude`, `Post`.`longitude`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`status`, `User`.`code`, `User`.`lastlogin`, `User`.`created` FROM `db52704_favorr`.`posts` AS `Post` LEFT JOIN `db52704_favorr`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Post`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `Post`.`status` IN (1, 2) AND `TopicPost`.`topic_id` = 1 ORDER BY `Post`.`datetime` desc LIMIT 15`

Comment: @Cameron: Are you sure you've copied the 'contain' line as well?

Comment: Yes that contain is there. If I comment out the TopicPost line in the conditions then I can debug and I get this statement: http://bin.cakephp.org/view/2082480982 as you can see TopicPost is not in the code AT ALL! Can you see anything wrong with the associations?

Comment: I've even made sure all my models have `public $actsAs = array('Containable');` but the contain isn't the issue as it's the conditions that causes the error...

Comment: @Cameron: How about with the update above? :) I don't think all of your models need Containable in this case, but if you want to add it to *all* models, simply add it to your AppModel.

Comment: Still get the same error! Added that code to the Post model as well.

Comment: @Cameron: I really don't know why that shouldn't work..maybe you should try to isolate the relevant code into a standalone app and try debugging from there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with your model relationships, I don't understand why you have a HABTM relationship on the posts model, when you are actually emulating this ([using the Has-many-through method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through)) on the `TopicPost` model itself. If you don't want to use the HABTM behaviour built into cake (and I don't blame you), you should setup relationships like this:

```
class PostTopic extends AppModel { // note PostTopic, name should be alphabetical
    public $belongsTo = array('Post', 'Topic');
}

class Post extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('PostTopic');
}

class Topic extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('PostTopic');
}
```

Then to fetch the IDs of posts or topics that relate, you simply load the `PostTopic` class and do a search:

```
// ie in Post Controller
$this->paginate($this->Post->PostTopic, array('PostTopic.topic_id' => $post['PostTopic']['topic_id']));
```

I have a similar setup on my site, where users can add a product to their inventory, It's kind of a HABTM relatipnship but with more data attached to it. See the Product, Inventory and Users models here for a more complicated [example](https://github.com/Dunhamzzz/Consumer-Love/tree/master/Model).

Comment: That last bit of code is wrong! The topic_id isn't the id of the current post!

Comment: @Cameron well you're supposed to replace it with the right variable, it will probably be `$post['PostTopic']['topic_id']` or something.

Comment: How would I do this with a paginate then?

Comment: Updated answer. It's quite simple once you get your head around has-many-through relationships in cake.

Comment: Well the method is in the TopicsController not the PostsController as I'm getting Posts for the Topic I'm viewing which is what the issue was as it seemed as though Cake couldn't understand the associations even though they are correct.

Comment: In that case just change `$this->Post` to `$this->Topic`! Also your associations were incorrect. [See here](https://github.com/Dunhamzzz/Consumer-Love/blob/master/Controller/UsersController.php#L185) for an example of where I'm doing the exact same thing you're trying to achieve; and for gods sake, play with the code to try to understand what it's doing instead of asking for answers on a plate, you'll never learn anything that way.

Comment: If my associations are incorrect how come it's working the way Hannibal Lecter has done it then all my data requests work fine across the app? And I have played with the code, who do you think wrote the code in the first place to get stuck :/

Comment: It works but look how much he's hacked it, I've done it in one line!

Comment: I've tried but I get this error: Undefined index: topic_id [APP/Controller/TopicsController.php, line 91] with this code: `$posts = $this->paginate($this->Topic->TopicPost, array('TopicPost.topic_id' => $topic['Topic']['topic_id'])); $this->set('posts', $posts);`

Comment: You need to replace `$topic['Topic']['topic_id']` with `$topic['Topic']['id']` - or whatever variable contains the topic ID you are looking for.

Comment: Okay that worked! What about adding all those extra params in though that I had? As I don't understand how to use them with the way in which you have implemented the paginate method. ALSO I haven't amended my associations and it still worked... so?

Comment: Read how to setup pagination params in the manual. I'm done here.

Comment: It doesn't work though -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303905/cakephp-paginate-controller-with-custom-conditions#comment13262637_10303905

Answer (score 0):

From question comment:

> Also just to note the DB structure and relationships work fine as I
>   can pull the topics for a post fine using TopicPost so I KNOW that
>   works, it's just getting Posts for a topic that seems to be not
>   working...

Right, because you setup the [HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) for Post->Topic, but not for Topic->Post. The 2.0 book defines an example just like yours (but using recipes and ingredients) to describe the use case.

> The main difference between hasMany and HABTM is that a link between
>   models in HABTM is not exclusive. For example, we’re about to join up
>   our Recipe model with an Ingredient model using HABTM. Using tomatoes
>   as an Ingredient for my grandma’s spaghetti recipe doesn’t “use up”
>   the ingredient. I can also use it for a salad Recipe.

The same can be said for a `Post` using a `Topic` (your name for a tag/category). And just like their example:

> Remember to define a HABTM association in the Ingredient model if
>   you’d like to fetch Recipe data when using the Ingredient model.

Or, in your case, the Topic model.

So here's the models that you should use:

```
class Post extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Post';

    public $belongsTo = 'User';

    public $hasMany = array('Answer');

    // Has many topics that belong to topic post join table... jazz
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Topic' => array('with' => 'TopicPost')
    );
}

class Topic extends AppModel
{
    // Has many posts that belong to topic post join table... jazz
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Post' => array('with' => 'TopicPost')
    );
}
```

Now, you don't really need `TopicPost` unless you are doing something special, but it is fine as it is. And, though you can use that model for adding `Topic`s to to a post (or vice-versa), I'd suggest you use the build in method of handling HABTM saves. Review [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-habtm) for details on saving HABTM.

If you decide to remove it, make sure you define the join tables and conditions for the HABTM options in each model [per the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm)

Comment: Updated my model to look like yours and I still get the same error as before!

Comment: @Cameron what error? That you are not getting `Post`s for a `Topic` via `Topic->find()`?